# How to Collect the list of Third Party Jars used in our Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are trying to collect all the thirdparty jars have been utilized in our project, so that we will have a control and clarification on the jars used by us.

Is there a Way to collect all the thirdparty jars have been used in maven project?

We are looking for any tool or command which will do this task for us.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven, try running:

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath
```

It will give you a list of all the jars that have been used in the said project. It will come as a long string where each jar path is separated by a `:` e.g:

`/this/is/path/one.jar:/this/is/path/two.jar:/this/is/path/three.jar`

Hope this helps :)